# Do Pyros have any fire resistance?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

Normally, when I'm blasting fellow Pyros with my flamethrower, they take no less damage per second from my flames than non-Pyros (ignoring afterburn). However, I've noticed that, when I shoot a Detonator shot at a Pyro, instead of taking the standard 30 damage (and afterburn), he takes only 11 damage.

Does this mean that the Pyro has some fire resistance (I know that Pyros are immune to afterburn, but I'm asking about whether they take the standard amount of fire damage that other classes take), or is this just a property of the Detonator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most weapons in TF2 have min\max damage. So no, Pyro does not have any resistance beyond immunity to afterburn if you take him with base stats. Some gear provide reduction of damage to certain elements, such as fire and explosives, so that can affect your overall damage output as well.

Also, some weapons have damage based on where you hit, such as a headshot is a lot more damage than a body shot for example. The ambassador comes to mind as it's guaranteed crit on headshot.

The detonator projectile deals 10-20 base damage, so that explains why you see "only" 11 damage dealt at times. Here is the TF2 wiki site for that weapon: https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Detonator

Comment: So, are the damage numbers on the TF2 wiki just averages?

Comment: @alexqwx The 30 damage is if you hit directly. The 10-20 damage means that if you detonate, then it will do between 10 and 20 damage, depending on distance to the centre of detonation.